# How to force Json.Net to serialize a an overrided field, where the parent classed marked it as [JsonIgnore]

Tags: c#, json, inheritance, serialization

I have a class `A` that define a virtual property `X`  like this:

```
public virtual string X { get; set; }
```

Most of the classes that extend `A` use A's definition of `X`, but class `B` overrides it and defines, and since it calculates it's value from another field, it is marked as

```
[JsonIgnore]
public override string X { get { return this.Y+Z; } }
```

There is however a third class C that extends B, but can't calculate X, so it needs a get/set and serialize the field

```
public override string X { get; set; }
```

The problem is that when I serialize `C`, `X` is being ignored, due to the `[JsonIgnore]` on the parent class `B`.

How can I get it to serialize `X` on `C`, but still keep it from serializing it on `B`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much while writing the question I thought on the solution, not using `override`, but rather `new` so that it considers it a new property, so I ended up definin `X` like this on `C`

```
public new string X { get; set; }
```

If this is not correct, please post an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `new` keyword on the implementation of `X` in class `C` instead of overriding the virtual member.  This should stop the annotation in class `B` from being inherited.

The only problem is it will break polymorphism:

```
A newObj = new C(); 
var b = newObj.X; //This calls the method in class A, not in C
```

Other options are to revisit your inheritance scheme... for example, can you make C directly inherit from A?